# The method add(String) is undefined for the type String (JSONObject 2nd Array)

Tags: android, mysql, arrays, json, addition

After reciving the Data from the PHP-File with a MySQL-query, I want to fill two Array with the data.
The first Array works:

```
results.add((String) json_data.get("product") + "\n" + json_data.get("owner"));
```

But when I add the second Array:

```
mysql_id.add((String) json_data.get("id"));
```

Eclipse displays a Error:

> The method add(String) is undefined for the type String

There a no suggestions available and I dont know the Problem.
I have "mysql_id" everywhere declard as "results" but it doesnt work!

Thanks for Help!

Comment: Can you show the declaration and initialisation of `results` and `mysql_id` please?

Comment: is `mysql_id` a String variable?

Comment: ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mysql_id = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like this

```
mysql_id.add(getString("id"));
```